# SVG and Div text into the one canvas

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I am working on a project whereby I have a form which a user fills out. The form has various options which alter the visual appearance of the  image. I have a seperate div which contains text from user input which I would like to place onto of the dynamic svg, output as a png and embed it into an email.

Here is the code attached to my submit button:

```
$('#form_check_out').submit(function() {        
$('#hidden-response').text('');

if ($(this).valid()) {

    $('#hidden-response').text('Congratulations! Your form has been submitted!');
    $('#hidden-response').fadeIn('slow');   
            //CREATE XML FROM THE SVG OBJECT

        var canvasTemp = document.getElementById("canvas-svg2");
        var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(document.getElementById("SVG_scene"));

        //DRAW XML ONTO THE CANVAS ELEMENT
        canvg(canvasTemp, sXML,{ ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true })

        rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(document.getElementById("text-top-bottom").innerHTML, canvasTemp);
        //dataURL represents to encoded PNG data 
        var dataURL = document.getElementById("canvas-svg2").toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("svg-text").value = dataURL;

        var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
        w.document.write("<img src='"+dataURL+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
        console.log(dataURL);

        post_data = {
            'c_name'        : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'c_address'     : $('input[name=address]').val(),
            'c_suburb'      : $('input[name=suburb]').val(),
            'c_postcode'    : $('input[name=postcode]').val(),
            'c_state'       : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'c_phone'       : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
            'c_fax'         : $('input[name=fax]').val(),
            'c_email'       : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'c_dataURL'     : $('input[name=notes]').val()
        };



        //Ajax post data to server
       $.post('http://localhost:8080/web/secure_email_code.php', post_data, function(response){
            $("#form_check_out").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    return false;
}else{
    alert("This form has problems, lets start validating!");
    $('#form_check_out').validate();
    $('#hidden-response').text('Please input all required fields to continue.');
    $('#hidden-response').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;           
}
```

});

The svg is added to the canvas-svg using canvg plugin and rasterHTML is used to add the div text to the canvas-svg. I would like to embed the canvas png into an email. My php code is as follows but for some strange reason c_DataURL is not returning a value in my email text

```
//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$c_name             = filter_var($_POST["c_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_address          = filter_var($_POST["c_address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_suburb           = filter_var($_POST["c_suburb"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_postcode         = filter_var($_POST["c_postcode"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_state            = filter_var($_POST["c_state"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_phone            = filter_var($_POST["c_phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_fax              = filter_var($_POST["c_fax"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$c_email            = filter_var($_POST["c_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$c_svg_text = $_POST['c_dataURL'];

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'http://localhost:8080/web/images/');

$c_svg_text = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $c_svg_text);
$c_svg_text = str_replace(' ', '+', $c_svg_text);
$c_svg_text = base64_decode($c_svg_text);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';//email body
$subject = "test";
$message_body = "Enquiry complete" . "\r\n" .
                "Name: ".$c_name."\r\n".
                "Address: ".$c_address."\r\n".
                "Suburb: ".$c_suburb."\r\n".
                "Postcode: ".$c_postcode."\r\n".
                "State: ".$c_state."\r\n".
                "Phone: ".$c_phone."\r\n".
                "Fax: ".$c_fax."\r\n".
                "Email: ".$c_email."\r\n".
                "Image: ".$c_svg_text."\r\n";

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xxx@xxx.com.au'."\r\n";

'Reply-To: '.$user_email.''."\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
```

I would be greatful if anyone can spot errors with what I have done so far... I just want to add svg and div to canvas then canvas to png, then png to embed into email. I know I am close... thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to display both the svg (using canvg.js) and the div (html2canvas) into the one canvas using the following code

```
$("#SaveIt").click(function () {
var canvasTemp = document.getElementById("canvas-svg2");
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
svg = document.getElementById("SVG_scene"); 
var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(svg);
canvg(canvasTemp, sXML,{ ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true })


html2canvas($("#text-top-bottom"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");



            var ctx = canvasTemp.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image;
                img.onload = function(){
                    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
                };
            img.src = myImage;
    }
});
```

});

When I right click on the canvas and view image I am presented with a long string representing the complete image dataURL, however, when I output the value of myImage to a textarea (not shown in code), the string is incomplete and only displays the div sent to the canvas with html2canvas. If I have both the SVG and the div information showing in the canvas, why cant I extract the entire dataURL of the whole canvas and display it into the textarea?